# Angular2 set value for formGroup

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

So I have a complex form for creating an entity and I want to use it for editing as well I am using new angular forms API. I structured the form exactly as the data I retrieve from the database so I want to set the value of the whole form to the data retrieved here is an example to what i want to do:

```
this.form = builder.group({
      b : [ "", Validators.required ],
      c : [ "", Validators.required ],
      d : [ "" ],
      e : [ [] ],
      f : [ "" ]
    });
this.form.value({b:"data",c:"data",d:"data",e:["data1","data2"],f:data});
```

PS: NgModel doesn't work with new forms api also i don't mind using one way data binding in template as in

```
<input formControlName="d" value="[data.d]" />
```

that works but it would be a pain in case of the arrays

Comment: As far as I know setting a forms value is currently not supported and will be supported after the next update (RC.5). Please provide a Plunker.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer check my current solution

Comment: Di you look at:
https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0-rc.5/modules/%40angular/forms/src/model.ts line 553 FormGroup.setValue() ?

Answer (score 395, accepted):

To set **all** FormGroup values use, **setValue**:

```
this.myFormGroup.setValue({
  formControlName1: myValue1, 
  formControlName2: myValue2
});
```

To set **only some** values, use **patchValue**:

```
this.myFormGroup.patchValue({
  formControlName1: myValue1, 
  // formControlName2: myValue2 (can be omitted)
});
```

With this second technique, not all values need to be supplied and fields whos values were not set will not be affected.

Comment: I'm using patchValue in a nested form and it is overwriting all the fields in the form. (even those I don't specify) any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @Enrico, without ur code I can not help u.

Answer (score 20):

You can use form.get to get the specific control object and use setValue

```
this.form.get(<formControlName>).setValue(<newValue>);
```

Comment: How to pass array to new value

Comment: @RaviShah it is JSON syntax

Answer (score 12):

For set value when your control is FormGroup can use this example

```
this.clientForm.controls['location'].setValue({
      latitude: position.coords.latitude,
      longitude: position.coords.longitude
    });
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can use setValue to set value for edit/update purpose.

```
this.personalform.setValue({
      name: items.name,
      address: {
        city: items.address.city,
        country: items.address.country
      }
    });
```

You can refer http://musttoknows.com/use-angular-reactive-form-addinsert-update-data-using-setvalue-setpatch/ to understand how to use Reactive forms for add/edit feature by using setValue. It saved my time

Answer (score 4):

As pointed out in comments, this feature wasn't supported at the time this question was asked. This issue has been resolved in angular 2 rc5

Answer (score 3):

I have implemented a temporary solution until angular2 support form updateValue

```
 initFormGroup(form: FormGroup, data: any) {
        for(var key in form.controls) {
          console.log(key);
          if(form.controls[key] instanceof FormControl) {
            if(data[key]){
              let control = <FormControl>form.controls[key];
              this.initFormControl(control,data[key]);
            }
          } else if(form.controls[key] instanceof FormGroup) {
            if(data[key]){
              this.initFormGroup(<FormGroup>form.controls[key],data[key]);
            }
          } else if(form.controls[key] instanceof FormArray) {
            var control = <FormArray>form.controls[key];
            if(data[key])
            this.initFormArray(control, data[key]);
          }
        }
      }
      initFormArray(array: FormArray, data: Array<any>){
    if(data.length>0){
      var clone = array.controls[0];
      array.removeAt(0);
      for(var idx in data) {
        array.push(_.cloneDeep(clone));
        if(clone instanceof FormGroup)
          this.initFormGroup(<FormGroup>array.controls[idx], data[idx]);
        else if(clone instanceof FormControl)
          this.initFormControl(<FormControl>array.controls[idx], data[idx]);
        else if(clone instanceof FormArray)
          this.initFormArray(<FormArray>array.controls[idx], data[idx]);
      }
    }
  }


initFormControl(control: FormControl, value:any){
    control.updateValue(value);
  }
```

usage:

```
this.initFormGroup(this.form, {b:"data",c:"data",d:"data",e:["data1","data2"],f:data});
```

note: form and data must have the same structure and i have used lodash for deepcloning jQuery and other libs can do as well

Answer (score 0):

> "NgModel doesn't work with new forms api".

That's not true. You just need to use it correctly. If you are using the reactive forms, the NgModel should be used *in concert with* the reactive directive. See [the example in the source](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0-rc.4/modules/%40angular/forms/src/directives/reactive_directives/form_control_name.ts#L64).

```
/*
 * @Component({
 *      selector: "login-comp",
 *      directives: [REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES],
 *      template: `
 *        <form [formGroup]="myForm" (submit)='onLogIn()'>
 *          Login <input type='text' formControlName='login' [(ngModel)]="credentials.login">
 *          Password <input type='password' formControlName='password'
 *                          [(ngModel)]="credentials.password">
 *          <button type='submit'>Log in!</button>
 *        </form>
 *      `})
 * class LoginComp {
 *  credentials: {login:string, password:string};
 *  myForm = new FormGroup({
 *    login: new Control(this.credentials.login),
 *    password: new Control(this.credentials.password)
 *  });
 *
 *  onLogIn(): void {
 *    // this.credentials.login === "some login"
 *    // this.credentials.password === "some password"
 *  }
 * }
 */
```

Though it looks like from the [TODO comments](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0-rc.4/modules/%40angular/forms/src/directives/reactive_directives/form_control_name.ts#L104), this will likely be removed and replaced with a reactive API.

```
// TODO(kara):  Replace ngModel with reactive API
@Input('ngModel') model: any;
```

Comment: coming from angular2 api docs 
NgModel selector 
[ngModel]:not([formControlName]):not([formControl])
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/NgModel-directive.html
so even if it works now it will be removed later i think i will implement a manual value injector as it will be a more stable solution

Comment: @AmgadSerry that is to make sure that it doesn't interfere with those components (in the selector). The `FormControlName` explicitly adds it as an `@Input()`. See the source I linked to. If those negating selectors weren't there, then with the example above, an NgModel would be created, which you don't want.

Comment: It's a little confusing, but that's just how it's implemented. For both `FormControlDirective` (`[formControl]`) and `FormControlName` (`formControlName`), this is how it works. If the `ngModel` is used without one of those, then it is assumed you will be using _declarative_ forms, and an `NgModel` is created. If the `ngModel` is used _alongside_ one of the _reactive_ form directives, then _that_ reactive form directive will handle the model, not an `NgModel`

Comment: oh i thought they made that as a hack to enable ngModel on those two directives only for the time being and they will remove it later

Comment: check my current solution