# How to bind data on angular material dropdown in angular 5?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, dropdown

basically i am Updating user profile on which i have a user info. which is to be  bind on the user respective fields.

```
    this.editOfferprice= new FormGroup({
        xyz : new FormControl(xxxx,[]),
        xxx: new FormControl(xxxx,[Validators.required]),
        wwwID : new FormControl(xxxx,[Validators.required]))};
```

on above code am using formgroup and formcontrol.

```
<mat-form-field fxFlex="49"> <mat-select placeholder="Select xxx" formControlName="xxx"> <mat-option *ngFor="let P of Pro" [value]="P.ID"> {{P.Name}} </mat-option> </mat-select> <mat-error *ngIf="editOffer.controls['xxx'].errors && editOfferprice.controls['xxx'].errors.required"> You must select NAme</mat-error> </mat-form-field>
```

i want to know how to bind data on dropdown?

Comment: I think it's your solution (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38655613/angular2-set-value-for-formgroup#39752561)

Answer (score 0):

use the `[ngValue]`

```
*ngFor="let P of Pro" [ngValue]="P.ID">
```

Comment: should work with `value` as well, see https://material.angular.io/components/select/examples

Answer (score 0):

Try binding using `ngModel` in the select like this -

```
<mat-form-field>
  <select matNativeControl [(ngModel)]="selectedOption" required>
    <option *ngFor="let P of Pro [value]="P.ID">{{P.Name}}</option>
  </select>
</mat-form-field>
```

or if you want to use formControl do it like this -

```
[formControl]="yourControl"
```

Due to [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17685) in Angular bind the **formControl** instance instead of using **formControlName**.

[Working Example](https://run.stackblitz.com/api/angular/v1?file=app%2Fselect-hint-error-example.ts)