# Insert value in formgroup reactive forms

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, formgroups

I have something like this

```
let formGroup = new FormGroup({
  operationalAM: new FormGroup({
    endTime: new FormControl('')
  }),
  operationalPM: new FormGroup({
    startTime: new FormControl('')
  })
});
```

I am trying to set value to **endTime** and **startTime** like this

```
formGroup.controls.operationalAM.value.endTime.setValue('1300');
formGroup.controls.operationalPM.value.startTime.setValue('');
```

But I am having error

**TypeError: formGroup.controls.operationalAM.value.endTime.setValue is not a function**

Does anybody knows hwo to set value to formGroup inside formGroup?

Comment: You need getter for the formcontrols

Comment: Check the demo I shared.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You set values in controls like this:

```
formGroup.controls.get('operationalAM').setValue({ endTime: '1300' });
formGroup.controls.get('operationalPM').setValue({ startTime: '1300' });
```

You can use the patchValue which [works like](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms):

> Use the patchValue() method to replace any properties defined in the object that have changed in the form model.

```
formGroup.controls.get('operationalAM').patchValue({ endTime: '1300' });
```

This way you keep the reference but update only the value of `endTime`

Comment: Error: Must supply a value for form control with name: 'endTime'.

Comment: It shouldn't be instantiated directly

Comment: What do you mean? you can use the patchValue to change just the endTime.

Comment: It is not exactly good practise to target controls directly, plus - i'm surprised this answer actually works (you shouldn't need the first reference to 'controls'). The only 'correct' way to do this is in my opinion is:  formGroup.get(['operationalAM', 'endTime']).setValue('1300').

Answer (score 2):

it should be

```
formGroup.controls.operationalAM.controls.endTime.setValue('1300');
formGroup.controls.operationalPM.controls.startTime.setValue('');
```

Comment: Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'.ts(2

Answer (score 0):

Since you have formGroup inside another formGroup, You should have to refer controls inside the inner formGroup

```
formGroup.controls.get('operationalAM.startTime').setValue('1300');
formGroup.controls.get('operationalPM.endTime').setValue('');
```

The second way is to use getter

like

```
 get startTime(){
  return this.yourform.get('operationalAM.startTime')
 }
 get endTime(){
  return this.yourform.get('operationalPM.endtime')
 }
```

This returns controls then you can set value for the controls like

```
this.yourform.get('endtime').setValue(value);
```

Comment: Error: It shouldn't be instantiated directly

Answer (score 0):

you can also use the patchValue Method as follows:

```
 formGroup.patchValue({
 operationalAM: ({
 endTime:'1'
 }),
operationalPM:({
 startTime:'2'
})
});
```

you don't need to specify all fields here only the ones you need

source: this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38655613/angular2-set-value-for-formgroup)